# Public Key Auth + Kerberos

Tags: ssh, openssh, kerberos

I've setup public key authentication for enabling `SSH` connection into my university machine. However, it only logs me in on the local machine and doesn't give me Kerberos credentials which I need for accessing my network folder. This causes problems with tools like git.

Is there a way for me to automatically get Kerberos credentials when connecting through `SSH` without entering my Kerberos password?

My client machine is OSX 10.6 and my university machine is Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kerberos will work only if you authenticate to Kerberos-enabled server by password. You can:

- set up kerberos trust for the incoming user if the user is already authenticated by known realm;
- enable GSSAPI forwarding of credentials on ssh client and server ('ssh -K', GSSAPIAuthentication for sshd), this would work if server and client belongs to the same kerberos domain.